# toastr doesn't appear in ui-router child states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, toastr

Below is an example of my parent/child states and the index.html file that renders my angular app. No `toastr` messages appear in the child states, not sure why. The dependency is included as expected in each controller.

**config.js**

```
(function(){
'use strict'

var app = angular.module('core');

app.config(AppRouter);

AppRouter.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];

function AppRouter($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $stateProvider
        .state('/', {
            templateUrl: 'app/components/home/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            parent: 'app',
            authenticate: true,
            resolvePolicy: {when:'LAZY', async: 'WAIT'},
            resolve:{
                security:['$q', '$rootScope', 'privileges', 'routeErrors', function($q, $rootScope, privileges, routeErrors){
                    if($rootScope.isLoggedIn()){
                        return $q.resolve();
                    } else {
                        return $q.reject(routeErrors.NOT_LOGGED_IN);
                    }
                }]
            }                   
        })
        .state('app', {
            url:'',
            abstract: true,
            template: '<div ui-view class="slide-animation"></div>',
            resolve:{
                privileges: ['privilegesService', function(privilegesService){
                    return privilegesService.getPrivileges()
                                            .then(privilegesService.privilegesData)
                                            .catch(privilegesService.getPrivilegesError);
                }],
                alarms: ['alarmsService', function(alarmsService){
                    return alarmsService.setAlarms();
                }],
                firmsData: ['chosenFirmService', function(chosenFirmService){
                    return chosenFirmService.getFirmsData();
                }],
                notifications: ['notificationsService', function(notificationsService){
                    notificationsService.loadNotificationData();
                    return notificationsService.setupGlobalAccess();
                }],
                releaseNotes: ['releaseNotesService', function(releaseNotesService){
                    return releaseNotesService.setupGlobalAccess(); 
                }],
                setIdle: ['idleService', function(idleService){
                    return idleService.setIdle();
                }] 
            }
        })
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/home/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            parent: 'app',
            authenticate: true,
            resolvePolicy: {when:'LAZY', async: 'WAIT'},
            resolve:{
                security:['$q', '$rootScope', 'privileges', 'routeErrors', function($q, $rootScope, privileges, routeErrors){
                    if($rootScope.isLoggedIn()){
                        return $q.resolve();
                    } else {
                        return $q.reject(routeErrors.NOT_LOGGED_IN);
                    }
                }]
            }                   
        })
}

app.config(Toastr);

function Toastr(toastrConfig) {
    angular.extend(toastrConfig, {
        autoDismiss: true,
        containerId: 'toast-container',
        maxOpened: 0,
        newestOnTop: true,
        positionClass: 'toast-top-center',
        preventDuplicates: false,
        preventOpenDuplicates: true,
        target: 'body',
        timeOut: 5000
    });
};
})();
```

**index.html**

```
<body data-ng-cloak>
    <div ng-include="'app/shared/partials/navbar.html'"></div>
    <div class="slide-animation-container">
        <div ui-view id="ng-view" class="slide-animation"></div>
        {{scrollTo}}
    </div>
    <div ng-include="'app/shared/partials/footer.html'"></div>
    <div ng-include="'app/shared/partials/loading.html'"></div>
</body>
```

**Sample controller (this happens in every child state of 'app')**

```
EditFirmController.$injectParams = ['$filter', '$window', '$rootScope', 'toastr'];

function EditFirmController($filter, $window, $rootScope, toastr) {

        var editFirmFail = function(resp){
        resetDropDowns();
        toastr.error($rootScope.ResponseFailMessage(resp), "Update failed.");
    };
```

**Rendered HTML**

[image]

Comment: Did you put the toastr library as a dependency of your angular app? something like `angular.module('app', ['toastr'])`

Comment: Yes, it's included. The toastr messages appear in the html, however they're simply not visible.

Comment: Do you able to reproduce it in Plunker/Fiddle/Codepen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you configure it as `positionClass: 'toast-top-center',`

It should be:

```
<div id="toast-container" 
     class="toast-top-center" 
     style="pointer-events: auto;">
</div>
```

However from your example (the image) you have other class: `parent-state` a.e.

```
<div id="toast-container" 
     class="parent-state" 
     style="pointer-events: auto;">
</div>
```

The `toast-container` id has style:

```
#toast-container {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999999;
}
```

So it should work

If you don't see the image means, somehow  class `parent-state` **(suppose your custom class)** replaces `toast-top-center`.

```
.toast-top-center {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

or even didn't load at all.

Comment: Sorry, that `parent-state` class was part of an attempt at debugging (I've replaced that screenshot). The `toast-top-center` class renders as expected. Could it be that the css either needs to be loaded into the parent state directly so it can be accessed by the children, or the nesting is somehow getting in the way of the css being applied?

Comment: @NealR in debug console you should see the css of `toast-top-center`. If you don't see it, means you didn't load css sources

Comment: That was it, there was a bug in my `gulpfile.js` preventing the .css file from loading *facepalm*

Comment: @NealR glad to hear.